# ImageSource Binding Caches Image

Tags: image, xaml, azure, uwp

I'm setting a `Border`'s `Background` property by using an `ImageBrush`. The `ImageSource` is bound to an `ImageUri` property on my `Contact` object.

```
<Border>
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageUri, Mode=OneWay}" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

I'm using Azure Blob storage to store the images and it's working fine. However, if I update the image on a contact which already has an image set, my `ImageBrush` doesn't display the change. I've tried restarting the app and it makes no difference. The image is definitely being updated, as I tried downloading it from the url and it gets the new image. Also, if I reinstall the app it shows the new image correctly. So it would seem that the app is automatically caching the old image and displaying that one instead of the new one. (I already suspected this, since it takes a bit to get the images the first time, but after that it's instant.)

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you need to explicitly tell it not to cache the image. Replacing my `ImageBrush` with:

```
<ImageBrush AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill">
    <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        <BitmapImage CreateOptions="IgnoreImageCache" UriSource="{Binding ImageUri, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
</ImageBrush>
```

fixed the issue for me.